# Connection of StorageExplorer to AzureStack not working

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-stack

I am connecting the Storage Explorer as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-stack/user/azure-stack-storage-connect-se). I also add the AzureRootCertificate as described.

My storage is shown, but as soon as I want do display the tables ("Load more"), I get the following error message:
[image]
Since the Visual Studio Server Explorer is not working for AzureStack either, there is no proper way to display the storage content.

Comment: How did you setup the storage account with keys? Add the steps and UI snapshots of how you added the storage account. (of course don't show us the key )

Comment: See the new [question] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49857286/connection-of-storageexplorer-to-azurestack-still-not-working)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After a longer discussion with a Microsoft SE it turned out, we had to update the Azure Stack Dev Kit (to v18.03). It is important to always use the current version. Unfortunatly the Dev Kit cannot be updated, but has to be reinstalled each time.

The above error was gone but another error appeared already during the connection process. See the new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49857286/connection-of-storageexplorer-to-azurestack-still-not-working).

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a proxy, make sure that you have configured the Storage Explorer proxy properly.
Verify the authentication protocol used by your proxy server. Storage Explorer does not currently support NTLM proxies.

Ensure that you are running the latest version of Storage Explorer: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-explorer-relnotes

If you encounter the error message ‘Authentication Error’ when performing any operations, on any Services, you consider reuploading the certificate. Launch the Storage Explorer in an elevated mode and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: The elevated mode does not help. Reuploading the certificate does not help either.

Comment: Only the proxy confuses me. The storage is executed  on the AzureStack itself. Therefore there should be no Proxy involevd...